# sed replace data in the nth column if the line begins with X

Tags: replace, sed, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
A|\^&|||something|||||somethingelse|||XZXZXZXXZ-C5|2013  
B|1||||ccccX|||||||||||||||||HERE||||||||||  
C|1|rfrfrfrf||^^^hghghghg|3||||||||||8||||||||||B| |||||  
D|1|^^^grpou|word|||||C||adam||2013|0123|  
E|1|G
```

I'd like to insert the text QQQ into the 3rd column of any row that begins with B. I've tried several things and have a few options but I think I've over complicated it in my diag.

Here are the results I hope I can come up with:

```
A|\^&|||something|||||somethingelse|||XZXZXZXXZ-C5|2013  
B|1|QQQ|||ccccX|||||||||||||||||HERE||||||||||  
C|1|rfrfrfrf||^^^hghghghg|3||||||||||8||||||||||B| |||||  
D|1|^^^grpou|word|||||C||adam||2013|0123|  
E|1|G
```

Any sed or awk one liner type suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}/^B/{$3="QQQ"}1'
```

If you want to prepend the text in the third column (if there happens to be any) instead of clobbering it,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}/^B/{$3="QQQ"$3}1'
```

To append instead, move the `$3` to the other side.

Comment: EXACTLY! what I was looking for I had a grep and a pipe in mine TYVM
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}/^B/{$3="QQQ"}1' zzzzzzzzzz
    A|\^&|||something|||||somethingelse|||XZXZXZXXZ-C5|2013  
    B|1|QQQ|||ccccX|||||||||||||||||HERE||||||||||  
    C|1|rfrfrfrf||^^^hghghghg|3||||||||||8||||||||||B||||||  
    D|1|^^^grpou|word|||||C||adam||2013|0123|  
    E|1|G

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^B/s/[^|]*/QQQ/3' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes no leading space in each record. It also *replaces* pre-existing contents of column 3

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '$1 ~ /^B/{$3="QQQ"};{print}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '/^B/{$3="QQQ"}7' file
```

Comment: Got tired of using `1`?

Comment: @Kevin I always use 7. since i feel right hand index finger is more convenient than left hand little finger. ;)

Comment: Interesting. 7 is the hardest number for me to reach. Perhaps I'll start using 9 though.

Comment: What I have found interesting about using `^1` is you can easily track down code @kent wrote. When you have someone asking an `awk` and saying I tried this, you quickly find out they asked a question before a got a solution from Kent.

Comment: @sudo_O oh.. I didn't think of that part..thx for the remind. so next time if I wrote stupid dirty awk codes in answer, I am gonna write `1`... ;)